# Nativescript getElementsByClassName() Error

Tags: javascript, dom, nativescript

I always get error when I try to getvalue from class after scrolling the screen

for example: on my phone, the screen will show 8 listitem, if I have more than 8 items, I need to scroll. And when I try to tap after scrolling, it is showing error.

here is my code

```
<GridLayout rows="*">
        <ListView row="0" items="{{ ListID }}" itemTap="onItemTap" class="list-group">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <StackLayout class="list-group-item">
                    <Label text="{{ ID || 'Downloading...' }}" textWrap="true" class="OutletID" />
                    <Label text="{{ Name || 'Downloading...' }}" textWrap="true" class="OutletName" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView> 
    </GridLayout>
```

and js

```
function onItemTap(args) {
    const index = args.index;
    const page = args.object;
    var test = page.getElementsByClassName('OutletID')[index].text;
    console.log(test);
}
exports.onItemTap = onItemTap;
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used nativescript before so take this with a grain of salt, but...

When you're using a component based library like NativeScript generally you don't want to fetch references to items in that component through some third party library. Using the dom to fetch those references is essentially that. You're assuming those elements are still even in the dom. Why would they render an element to the dom, then hide it? My guess is what they're doing under the hood is removing the element from the dom when it scrolls up and off the page which is why your lookup is failing. You get an index > 7, the page will only show 8, so when you ask the page for all of them, you get a list back of size 8 and then you try to get the 9th element (with index 8).

So I think the solution to your problem is to stop trying to "go around" the component model and instead work with the methods and values provided to you by the NativeScript framework.

In your onItemTap() you should be able to get a reference to the item that was tapped directly. So I think you could should look something like this.

```
function onItemTap(args) {
    console.log(args.item.text);
}
```

itemTap Emitted when an item in the  is tapped. To access the tapped item, use event.item.

I couldn't find any definition for the class "itemTap" so I'm blind about what methods or attributes it has but here's where I found a reference to it. If you're trying to scrape a value off the dom itself (like the text attribute) you may need to do something like `args.item.rawElement.text` but that's specific to the API.

https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/#events

Comment: thank you for your advice. now i know what i have to do.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` is not a built-in method, it should be available only if you have installed the [nativescript-dom](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-dom) plugin.

ListView operates quite differently than other components, it recycles the template as you scroll down / up for better performance so using `getElementsByClassName` here would not be a wise idea.

```
function onItemTap(args) {
    const index = args.index; // The index that was tapped
    const view  = args.view; // The item instance that was tapped
    const data = view.bindingContext // will return enter data item
}
```

Source: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/list-view

Answer (score 0):

i edited my js like this :

```
function onItemTap(args) {
    const index = args.index;
    const val = vm.ListID[index].Name;
    console.log(val);
}
exports.onItemTap = onItemTap;
```

note : vm is pagebindingContext and **Name** ('OutletID') is my array ListID({ ID : ID, Name : Name})